# Prevent Double Submit on ASP.NET MVC page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 view. In the view, I have

```
<form action="/myAction" method="post">
  ...
  <input type="submit" value=" Save&nbsp;" onclick="this.disabled = true; this.value = ' Please wait... '; return true;" />
</form>
```

By disabling the button, the form never gets submitted. However, I would like to disable the button after a user clicks it. The reason I want to disable it is to prevent the user from clicking the "submit" button multiple times. What am I doing wrong? I thought if I returned true, the form would still submit.

Comment: Why on earth are you using obtrusive javascript to handle your onclick events?  If you are using MVC helper methods (such as Ajax.BeginForm) there are lots of ways to handle this type of scenario.

Comment: agree with @DavidL. To expand on his point, this doesn't look like an ajax call... so I'm lost why the user would get the chance to resubmit. Are they sent back to an exact duplicate form where you don't want them to hit submit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disable the button in your form's submitted event, not the button's click event. This is because the click event fires before the form is submitted - though you are returning `true`, so that shouldn't cause the submission to fail, I don't think.

Answer (score 0):

Use ActionFilters. [This blog post](http://rionghost.azurewebsites.net/2013/02/24/prevent-repeated-requests-using-actionfilters-in-asp-net-mvc/) has a class you can just drop into your project, decorate your actions and you're done.

Comment: Better use javascript, i've tryed that solution but is not perfect.